# Why care about the value of the action which I'm not gonna take in policy iteration?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-iteration

In [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/policy-iteration-in-rl-an-illustration-6d58bdcb87a7), there is an explanation (with an example) of how policy iteration works.

It seems that, if we replace all the probabilities of moves in the example by new probabilities where the best action is taken 100% of the time and the other moves are taken 0% of the time, then the final policy will end up to be (south, south, north) as in the example provided. However, if we are certain of our moves, we can go north and then south in the example to get most of the reward.

In other words, it seems to be incorrect to calculate the value of a state by summing up rewards for all possible actions out of the state, because, like in the case I described above, or a case where one action gives you a huge penalty, you are 100% gonna avoid it, therefore the value state is unfairly weighted.

Why care about the value of the action which I'm not gonna take?

Comment: If you knew that you should take an action $100 \%$ of the time, then, of course, you should always take it, but this is rarely the case. The transition probabilities should reflect how likely you should take the actions, but it's possible that whoever wrote the MDP didn't do it right. To give you a more concrete answer, I would read that article, but I can't unless I sign up/in with Google or Facebook, which I won't do.

Comment: @nbro Weird, I can open it without registration. Maybe there's some pop up you just have to close? Anyways, even if it's not 100%. Check this image: https://i.imgur.com/5hzZ5k7.png. If I go up and lets say upper path has 90% probability to go +1 when I choose to and 90% go -3 if I choose to and 10% the latter and lower path splits on 50% (no matter what I choose), then lower path will seem better even though is clearly not because for the upper path I will sum both moves 90/10 +1 and 90/10 -3 even though one would never choose to willingly play move where 90% chance is to end up in -3.